# React router header and footer showing but not the page content on refresh

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm using react router and when the page loads fine if I navigate there from another page but if I refresh the page or type in the URL only `<Header />` and `<Footer />` render.

The page in question is `/admin/messageRules/all`.  Here is my router code:

```
import React from "react";
import {Redirect, Route, BrowserRouter as Router, Switch} from "react-router-dom";

import Footer from "./components/Footer";
import Forgot from "./components/Forgot";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import Home from "./components/Home";
import Login from "./components/Login";
import MessageRules from "./components/MessageRules";
import PrivacyPolicy from "./components/PrivacyPolicy";
import Register from "./components/Register";
import Reset from "./components/Reset";
import TermsOfUse from "./components/TermsOfUse";

export const App = () => (
    <Router>
        <div>
            <Header />
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/admin" component={Home} />

                <Route path="/admin/messageRules/all" component={MessageRules} />
                <Route path="/PrivacyPolicy" component={PrivacyPolicy} />
                <Route path="/TermsOfUse" component={TermsOfUse} />

                <Route path="/Register" component={Register} />
                <Route path="/Login" component={Login} />
                <Route path="/Forgot" component={Forgot} />
                <Route path="/Reset" component={Reset} />
            </Switch>
            <Footer />
        </div>
    </Router>
);

export default App;
```

#### Update

The console is printing this error:

```
error:  SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at Navbar._callee$ (Navbar.jsx:31)
    at tryCatch (runtime.js:45)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (runtime.js:271)
    at Generator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (http://localhost:1337/front.js:46313:21)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (asyncToGenerator.js:3)
    at _next (asyncToGenerator.js:25)
```

Comment: Have you considered using a [`Switch`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Switch.md) rather than just a bunch of `Route`s?

Comment: So if you click a link to go to `"/admin/messageRules/all"`, it works fine but if you refresh, it doesn't load `MessageRules`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm new to react router and I have looked at switches but would that help me with this issue?

Comment: @TomFinney that's right.  It loads the page but only shows the header and footer without messageRules content.

Comment: Do you see any errors or warnings in the console? Does that component require any data that would be loaded by other components? I don't know whether a Switch would make any difference, that was just the first thing that stood out.

Comment: @Dev01 The `Switch` is useful if you only want one component to be rendered per route. E.g. without a switch, multiple components can be rendered that matches the current path so if you have something like `<Route path="/admin/something" component={Something} />` and `<Route path="/admin/something/else" component={SomethingElse} />` and you were on `/admin/something/else`, both components would be rendered.

Comment: @Dev01 can you put together a https://codesandbox.io/ or some way to demo and replicate this? It seems like it should work fine on refresh if you can navigate to that component directly.

Comment: @jonrsharpe @TomFinney I've updated my question with a `<Switch />` and the error that I see in the console

Comment: That looks to be unrelated to what you've posted: where is the `Navbar` (in the `Header`, maybe)? Are you using sagas, or something else with a generator? What's the request that's resulting in invalid JSON?

Comment: `Unexpected token < in JSON` so there is a token `<` in the JSON. and what is that JSON and where it comes from? what is NavBar ?  none are mentioned in your question

Comment: Thanks all!  See the answer I created for what was wrong but it was your help that got me there.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issues was with expressjs.  I had:

```
app.get("/admin", (req, res, next) => { ... });
```

and changed it to:

```
app.get("/admin*", (req, res, next) => { ... });
```

The reason the error referenced `Navbar` was because it was somehow trying to render some code from the landing page of the site and not the admin.

Thanks for the help!